# Does $x_n \rightharpoonup 0$, where $\|x_n \| \leq 1$ imply $Ax_n\rightarrow 0$, when $A$ is a compact, self-adjoint projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, compact-operators, weak-topology

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequences in a Hilbert space $H$, with $\|x\|\leq 1$, where $x_n \rightharpoonup 0$. Let $A: H\rightarrow H$ be a linear, compact, self-adjoint projection i.e. $A^2=A$ and $A=A^*$. Then $(A x_n)$ is relativally compact i.e. any sequence from $\overline{\lbrace Ax_1, Ax_2,\ldots\rbrace}$ has a  convergent subsequence.

How can I prove $\|A x_n\|\rightarrow 0$?

Note that $x_n \rightharpoonup 0$ means $x_n$ converges weakly to $0$. In a Hilbert space this is equivalent in saying $|\langle x_n, y\rangle|\rightarrow 0$ for all $y\in H$.

I thought this way:

$\|A x_n\|^2= \langle Ax_n,Ax_n\rangle=\langle x_n,Ax_n\rangle$

Since $A$ is a selfadjoint projection.

And since $\langle x_n,Ax_k\rangle\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, one could conclude that the diagonalsequence $\langle x_n,Ax_n\rangle$ also converge to $0$ for $n\rightarrow  \infty$.

But do I then really need the compactness of $A$?

Comment: compactness implies continuity, then $Ax_n \rightharpoonup0$ and the claim follows.

Comment: this question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551677/t-compact-operator-implies-that-every-weakly-convergent-sequence-x-n-implies?rq=1

Note also that neither self-adjointness nor to be a projection is needed for this. Compact operators are weak-norm-continuous.

Comment: But why should $Ax_n\rightharpoonup 0$ imply $Ax_n\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @ThusleGadelankz Thank you I got it now!

Comment: But just for the sake of interesst, would $A$ being not compact, but a self-adjoint projection also be sufficient to imply $A x_n\rightarrow 0$? I scetched a proof above.

Comment: @ThusleGadelankz Yes! Thank you!

Comment: No, it is not sufficient that $A$ be a self-adjoint projection. The identity operator is a self-adjoint projection and there exist weakly convergent sequences that are not norm convergent as soon as $H$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @ThusleGadelankz Oops sorry, did not see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in total $5$ needless assumptions. First $||x_{n}||\leq 1$ is not needed. **Firstly**, A weakly convergent seuqence is always bounded and it is the boundedness that you'll end up using. **Secondly**, as everyone mentioned in the comments, self adjointness. And the **third** is that this result is true in Banach spaces. It might not be proper to call the third needless as one may end up in a Hilbert space. **Fourth**, The operator need not be a projection. And **lastly**, the sequence may converge to any point $x$.

Here's the most general form and proof.

Let $X,Y$ be normed linear spaces such that $X$ is Banach and $A:X\to Y$ be a compact operator. Then for any $x_{n}\xrightarrow{w} x$, you have that $Ax_{n}\xrightarrow{||\cdot||} Ax$.

First you show that $Ax_{n}\xrightarrow{w} Ax$. This is easy as for any $g\in Y^{*}$ , you have that $g\circ A\in X^{*}$ . Thus $g(Ax_{n})\to g(Ax)$ for all $g\in Y^{*}$.

Now consider $Ax_{n_{k}}$ to be an arbitrary subsequence of $Ax_{n}$.

Weakly convergent sequences are bounded by an use of Uniform Boundedness Principle and here's where I require $X$ to be Banach.

So by compactness, $Ax_{n_{k}}$ will have a convergent subsequence $Ax_{n_{k_l}}$ (By definition of compact operators) . But where does it converge to? You see that this sub-subsequence already converges weakly to $Ax$ and hence, if it converged in norm, it must do so to the same point $Ax$ again.

Thus given any subsequence $Ax_{n_{k}}$ there exists a further subsequence $Ax_{n_{k_{l}}}$ which converges to $Ax$. This means that the whole sequence $Ax_{n}$ converges to $Ax$.

(A sequence $x_{n}$ in a metric space converges to $x$ if and only if given any subsequence, there exists a further subsequence which converges to $x$.)

Comment: Thank you, I got it now. I was just not sure which of these assumptions are really needed, so I just mentioned all of them.